# How do I write all iterations of reduce to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, amazon-emr, reduce

The idea behind the script is as follows:
I am filtering the original array by removing all even values from it. Next, I form a new array from the partial products of the original array:

```
// new first element = 1 * 3;
// second = (first (previous multiplication) * current value) = 3 * 3 (9);
// third = (previous product * current value) = 9 * 9 (81)
```

I got the results I wanted, but my output doesn't look like an array:

```
Input:
3 3 9

Output:
3
9
81
```

Please help me draw the following output:

```
Input:
3 3 9

Output:
3 9 81
```

```js
function modify(arr) {
  var result = [];

  arr = arr.filter(item => !(item % 2 == 0))
    .reduce(function(acc, curItem) {
      console.log(acc * curItem);
      return acc * curItem;
    }, 1)

  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    arr.push(result[i]);
  };
  return result;
}

console.log( modify([3,3,9]) )
```

Comment: `result` is always empty. The body of the `for` loop is therefor never executed.

Comment: You have everything you need in your script. Play with it and have another look at how [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) works and the examples in the documentation. You can not only return a number.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo That's not the problem here. Also this would make the `return result` useless by introducing an unnecessary global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` keeping track of both your cumulative product, and the final array:

```js
const input = [3, 3, 9];

const output = input.reduce( (acc,val) => {
   const newResult = acc.cum * val;
   acc.result.push(newResult);
   acc.cum = newResult;
   return acc;
},{cum:1, result:[]});

console.log(output.result);
```

As the last element of the array is always the cumulative product, you could also write it like this:

```js
const input = [3, 3, 9];

const output = input.reduce( (acc,val) => {
   const newResult = (acc.length ? acc[acc.length-1] : 1) * val;
   acc.push(newResult);
   return acc;
},[]);

console.log(output);
```

It's up to you which one of these you find easier to work with.

Comment: `cum` is the same as the last entry in `result`

Comment: @Andreas It is for everything other than the first iteration where it needs a 1. I guess I could do `acc.length ? acc[length-1] : 1` but I thought this way was clearer.

Comment: Or use the index, which would be the third argument of `.reduce()`

Comment: *"I guess I could do `acc.length ? acc[length-1] : 1`"* ... or `acc.slice(-1)[0] ?? 1` or the already suggested `idx` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

With `Array#reduce()` method and the `spread` operator you can transform your array as in the following demo:

```js
let modify = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc,cur,i) => [...acc, (acc[i-1] || 1) * cur],[]);

console.log( modify([3,3,9]) );
```

Or simply:

```js
function modify(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc,cur,i) { 
        return [...acc, (acc[i-1] || 1) * cur] 
    }, []);
}

console.log( modify([3,3,9]) );
```

Or if this is code that runs once, in which case you don't need a function:

```js
let oldArray = [3,3,9];

let newArray = oldArray.reduce(function(acc,cur,i) { 
    return [...acc, (acc[i-1] || 1) * cur] 
}, []);

console.log( newArray );
```

Comment: @ИльяКалошин feel free to upvote (^) this or the other answer if you found either or both useful. And you can as well accept one of the answers as the answer if it what helped you solve your problem.

Comment: I click vote but nothing changes. This is my first time on the Stack.